# MySQL sporadic MATCH AGAINST behaviour with unique index

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb, unique-index, sqlfiddle

When adding a unique key to a multi-table fulltext boolean search, the results cycle through 1 of 3 arbitrary states, with only 1 being correct.

Bear this in mind when checking the sqlfiddle below, as the query MAY initially work correctly - in such case, add whitespace to the left panel then rebuild and rerun - then it should be broken (but it's very hit-and-miss).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d95ba/18

Here's the query in question:

```
SELECT `i`.`item_id`, `g_a`.`alias` AS `group`, `i`.`name` AS `name`
  FROM `item` `i`
  JOIN `group_alias` `g_a` USING (group_id)
    WHERE
      MATCH (`g_a`.`alias`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR
      MATCH (`i`.`name`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Simple enough.  But with the following unique index addition:

```
ALTER TABLE `item_with_unique` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_item_group` (`group_id`, `name`)
```

the results cycle arbitrarily between these three states:

1. All rows are returned as if there was no WHERE clause
2. The alias matches are return as if there was no OR part to the WHERE clause
3. Correct results are returned (from my experiences, this has been the rarest)

Behaviour seems to be consistent to whichever of these 3 states it's in until the query is changed in some minor way (adding brackets, say) or the schema is rebuilt - at which point there's a chance it might change.

Is these some sort of restriction I've missed in the MySQL docs that describes this behaviour?  Is it a bug?  Or have I just done something obviously wrong?

Mysql Version 5.6.35 (sqlfiddle at time of writing).

Sqlfiddle for posterity in case the link dies:

```
CREATE TABLE `group` (
  `group_id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(256),
  FULLTEXT INDEX `search` (`name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `group_alias` (
  `group_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `alias` VARCHAR(256),
  CONSTRAINT `alias_group_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
    REFERENCES `group` (`group_id`),
  FULLTEXT INDEX `search` (`alias`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `item_id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `group_id` INT UNSIGNED,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `item_group_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
    REFERENCES `group` (`group_id`),
  FULLTEXT INDEX `search` (`name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `item_with_unique` LIKE `item`;
ALTER TABLE `item_with_unique` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_item_group` (`group_id`, `name`);

INSERT INTO `group` (`group_id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Thompson');
INSERT INTO `group` (`group_id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'MacDonald');
INSERT INTO `group` (`group_id`, `name`) VALUES (3, 'Stewart');

INSERT INTO `group_alias` (`group_id`, `alias`) VALUES (1, 'Tomson');
INSERT INTO `group_alias` (`group_id`, `alias`) VALUES (2, 'Something');
INSERT INTO `group_alias` (`group_id`, `alias`) VALUES (3, 'MacStewart');

INSERT INTO `item` (`item_id`, `group_id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 1, 'MacTavish');
INSERT INTO `item` (`item_id`, `group_id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 1, 'MacTavish; Red');
INSERT INTO `item` (`item_id`, `group_id`, `name`) VALUES (3, 2, 'MacAgnew');
INSERT INTO `item` (`item_id`, `group_id`, `name`) VALUES (4, 3, 'Spider');
INSERT INTO `item` (`item_id`, `group_id`, `name`) VALUES (5, 2, 'blahblah');

INSERT INTO `item_with_unique` SELECT * FROM `item`;


SELECT `i`.`item_id`, `g_a`.`alias` AS `group`, `i`.`name` AS `name`,
IF(MATCH (`g_a`.`alias`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE), 1, 0) AS `group_match`,
IF(MATCH (`i`.`name`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE), 1, 0) AS `item_match`
  FROM `item` `i`
  JOIN `group_alias` `g_a` USING (group_id)
    WHERE
      MATCH (`g_a`.`alias`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR
      MATCH (`i`.`name`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

SELECT "Same query, using table with unique index (NOTE: sporadically this is actually correct, in such case, skip to bottom notes)";
SELECT `i`.`item_id`, `g_a`.`alias` AS `group`, `i`.`name` AS `name`,
IF(MATCH (`g_a`.`alias`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE), 1, 0) AS `group_match`,
IF(MATCH (`i`.`name`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE), 1, 0) AS `item_match`
  FROM `item_with_unique` `i`
  JOIN `group_alias` `g_a` USING (group_id)
    WHERE
      MATCH (`g_a`.`alias`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR
      MATCH (`i`.`name`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

SELECT "Union of the two OR match conditions seperately (expected result from second query)";
SELECT `i`.`item_id`, `g_a`.`alias` AS `group`, `i`.`name` AS `name`,
IF(MATCH (`g_a`.`alias`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE), 1, 0) AS `group_match`,
IF(MATCH (`i`.`name`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE), 1, 0) AS `item_match`
  FROM `item_with_unique` `i`
  JOIN `group_alias` `g_a` USING (group_id)
    WHERE
      MATCH (`g_a`.`alias`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION
SELECT `i`.`item_id`, `g_a`.`alias` AS `group`, `i`.`name` AS `name`,
IF(MATCH (`g_a`.`alias`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE), 1, 0) AS `group_match`,
IF(MATCH (`i`.`name`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE), 1, 0) AS `item_match`
  FROM `item_with_unique` `i`
  JOIN `group_alias` `g_a` USING (group_id)
    WHERE
      MATCH (`i`.`name`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

SELECT "Now rebuild the schema (add a newline somewhere so sqlfiddle thinks it has changed) and observe that the results of the second query.  It may take multiple attempts but it usually cycles between 3 states:";
SELECT "1: Returns ALL results as if there were no conditions (5 rows)";
SELECT "2: Returns results as if there were no second part to the OR condition (1 row)";
SELECT "3: Returns the correct results (rarely)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `IGNORE INDEX` to your statement:

```
SELECT `i`.`item_id`, `g_a`.`alias` AS `group`, `i`.`name` AS `name`
  FROM `item` `i`
  IGNORE INDEX (unique_item_group)
  JOIN `group_alias` `g_a` USING (group_id)
    WHERE
      MATCH (`g_a`.`alias`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR
      MATCH (`i`.`name`) AGAINST ('Mac*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

MySQL is incredibly dumb to randomly use `unique_item_group` also for full-text search.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one-word names and aliases.  And you are checking for entire values or leading values.  Then FULLTEXT is not the type of index you need.

A simple `INDEX(name)`, together with `name LIKE 'Mac%'` would be very efficient.

If you have a long phrase with lots of words, and "MacDonald" might be in the middle of it, *then* `FULLTEXT` and `MATCH ... AGAINST` is the right way to go.

With either type of indexing,

```
WHERE table1 ...
   OR table2 ...
```

will be inefficient.  Roughly speaking, the optimizer will have to do a "cross join" to get all combinations of rows between the two tables, *then* see which of those match one or other match/like.

Perhaps you have "overnormalized" the data?  Can't both the `name` and `alias` be in the same table?  The query will be much faster, *and* there will be optimization techniques to make it *even faster*.  What you have will be noticeably slow with only 1K rows; what I propose can be optimized beyond millions, maybe billions of rows.

Comment: Concerning points about the inefficiency.  Firstly though, this is just an example set of data - fulltext IS what I'm looking for.  Also it's not overnormalized because items can have multiple aliases.
Regarding your comment about the cross join, surely this would be limited by the existing inner join between the two tables being searched through so wouldn't perform badly?  I don't see why it would have to cross join ALL rows on top of that, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` -- I think it will show a cross join (by saying ALL and ALL).  The problem is with `OR` across two tables.  I could imagine an ugly mess involving a `UNION` (to avoid the `OR` and allow the Optimizer to use `FULLTEXT` on _each_ table), and some subqueries to put the stuff back together.  Shall I tackle that?

Comment: You're right, it does show ALL and ALL.  However the union alternative doesn't look much better, with 2 fulltexts and 3 ALLs.  I think I may need to consider a completely different approach - thanks for bringing this to my attention.  However, the abstract strange mysql behaviour is still of interest to me.

Comment: I've come to a better solution using a cache table so all the fulltext indexes are on the same table - thanks again for your advice.

Comment: Please show me the query and the EXPLAIN; something did not work; it should not say ALL.

Comment: The query was just the posted query split unto two with 1 half of the OR each and a union between.  Again, solved now using a cache table so the only outstanding concern is why MySQL behaves like this with unique keys.

Comment: `FULLTEXT` has no concept of `UNIQUE`.

Comment: The unique key doesn't exist for fulltext purposes - I'm not expecting it to make unique matches - it exists purely for preventing duplicates through inserts and updates.  Fulltext behaviour shouldn't force you to not have a unique index that you may need for some other purpose.

Comment: If you can shrink to `(255)` (or less), then you can have both `FULLTEXT(name)` and `UNIQUE(name)`.